# url multiple slashes right after domain/port cause 404, in asp.net core v5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, http-status-code-404, url-routing

**Question**:
In .Net Core v5.0 apps:

- How to catch URL such as: "http://localhost:5000//" or "http://localhost:5000///"??
- Is there a way to catch such URL with Route configuration?
- Or, is there a way to catch such URL in IIS?

*These URLs are OK (200, not 404) in **.NET Core v2.1** apps.*

**Problem**:
http://localhost:5000    - //200 OK
http://localhost:5000/   - //200 OK
http://localhost:5000//   - //404 (**more than 1 slashes: cause 404**)
http://localhost:5000///  - //404

Console info: (pay attention to the **double slashes "//"** after localhost:5000)

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000// - - - 404 0 - 12.1067ms
```

While, URL with multiple slashes in the middle of the URL path (not right after domain/port) can be caught and handled.

**Environment**: 
1.asp.net core v5.0
2.Route Configuration:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseMvc(routes => //attribute routing is always available
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

3.Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Title = "WebApplication1";

    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
    host.Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

4.web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Tested in .net core v2.1, v3.1, v5.0, "http://localhost:5000///" shows the normal home index page in v2.1, while showing 404 in v3.1 and v5.0.

Answer (score 1):

> Or, is there a way to catch such URL in IIS?

You could use url rewrite in IIS to rewrite the `\\\` to "".

You could install the url rewrite by using this [extension](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Then you could add below url rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Remove multiple slashes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{REQUEST_URI}" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{UNENCODED_URL}" pattern="(.*?)[/]{2,}$" />
      </conditions>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Result:

[image]

---

Add below codes into Configure method:

```
        var options = new RewriteOptions()
.AddRedirect(@"(.*?)[/]{2,}$", "/");
        app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This does solve the problem on IIS for .net core v5.0.  I was wondering is there a way to catch such url in code? In .net core v2.1, such url does not cause 404 without url-rewrite.

Comment: update: modify the pattern to `<add input="{UNENCODED_URL}" pattern="[/]{2,}" />` to catch url with multiple slashes in the middle (not just the end).

Comment: In my opinion, we could capture this url in codes, we could use a custom middleware to monitor the url, if the url contains the ///, we could modify it to /.  Also asp.net core contains build-in url rewrite middleware, we could use it instead of using url rewrite rule. More details, you could refer to my update answer.